# How to open the default text editor from a webpage

Tags: html

I have a webpage (built using ASP.NET) with a list of text files. I want users to be able to click on a file and have it open using the default text editor.

It is expected that users already have the file in question, I really just have to open it.

*EDIT:* Only need to support Windows & Firefox & Chrome at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow you regarding the opening of files. You mean the users already have those files on their system, or are they going to download them from the server?

Comment: Are you in the position of a domain admin over these users?

Comment: Unless you let the user install a plugin, you can't really open arbitrary files or applications through the web browser. That'd be quite the security risk, not to mention annoying. You can offer a file for download, but what exactly the browser will do with it is not up to you.

Comment: @ChasingDeath yes, users already have the files. Imagine a build system interface that tells you which files failed to build, I want users to be able to click on those files and open the editor :)

Comment: @deceze if we only consider Windows + Chrome, would it be possible? I was thinking maybe there's a protocol like _mail://_ or the way Spotify opens songs from links (I know we can register those in the registry but I was trying to avoid creating a new one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I think you can do is force the files as downloads using the Response.ContentType with something like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

If you pipe the contents of the file directly to the Response stream (thus forcing the download), it would prompt the user to save or open the file in a text editor. I think this is the closest you're going to get without inventing your own protocol.

Comment: That sounds great. I've marked as correct even though it isn't exactly what I was looking for, as you said, this is probably the closest I'll get :) This is probably enough to give me more ideas hehe. Thanks a lot!